# Unable to understand parallelized code output in ray

Tags: python-3.x, ray

If I understand correctly the following piece of code should run in parallel

```
@ray.remote
class Worker:
  ...

  def train(self, item, i):
    time.sleep(i)
    logging.info(f'{i} {item}')
...

worker = Worker.remote()
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
results = ray.get([worker.train.remote(item, len(list) - idx) for idx, item in enumerate(list)])
print(results)
logging.info("successful print")
```

This should output

```
1 c
2 b
3 a
[1,2,3]
```

However, this outputs:

```
3 a
2 b
[3,2,1]
```

I am new to using ray and am unable to understand this behaviour. If anyone could point me towards the right direction, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

Actor is running within a single process. As a result, worker.train.remote() will be synchronous.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I was under the impression that ray.remote decorator created actors and that when invoking func.remote, it would trigger parallel executions of the actors.

Comment: Check this out. https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/walkthrough.html#remote-classes-actors This mentions `Each actor runs in its own Python process`.